# Remove a space white on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In a code bootstrap, I wanted to go up the button towards horizontal bar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPUwg.png)

```
<div class="separator-breadcrumb border-top"></div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
                  <button (click)="showPreviousYear()" *ngIf="showPreviousYearButton()" class="btn btn-primary ">
                      &lt; {{previousYear}}
                  </button>
                  <button (click)="showNextYear()" *ngIf="showNextYearButton()" class="btn btn-primary mx-1">
                      {{nextYear}} &gt;
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="lines.length > 0">
                  <table class="table table-striped">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th scope="col" style="width: 25%;">{{'4391' | t}}</th>
                              <th scope="col" style="width: 25%; text-align: right;">{{'4392' | t}}</th>
                              <th scope="col" style="width: 25%; text-align: right;">{{'4393' | t}}</th>
                              <th scope="col" style="width: 25%; text-align: right;">{{'4394' | t}}</th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           <tr *ngFor="let line of lines; let i = index">
                              <th style="width: 25%;">
                                    {{line.LIBELLE}}
                              </th>
                               <td style="width: 25%; text-align: right;">
                                    {{line.TAUX | number:'1.2-2' | mynamformatnum}} %
                               </td>
                               <td style="width: 25%; text-align: right;">
                                    {{line.BASE | number:'1.2-2' | mynamformatnum}} EUR
                               </td>
                               <td style="width: 25%; text-align: right;">
                                    {{line.MONTANT | number:'1.2-2' | mynamformatnum}} EUR
                               </td>
                          </tr>
                       </tbody>
                  </table>
              </div>

                <h5 *ngIf="lines.length == 0">
                    {{'4395' | t }}
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added a class `btn-top` in css

```
<button (click)="showPreviousYear()" *ngIf="showPreviousYearButton()" class="btn btn-primary btn-top">
```

And

```
.btn-top {
    position: relative; 
    top: -100px;
}
```

Now, I will want to remove the space white of the table, I don't find the class bootstrap to apply that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ0wJ.png)

Comment: Why don't you provide the buttons along with the heading instead of with the table ?

Comment: @Abin Thaha: I thought about that, but I don't know about bootstrap.

Comment: Along with the heading, give the buttons, separate them using col-6. Easy

Comment: @Abin Thaha: It's ok now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For alignment of button, Along with the heading, give the buttons, separate them using col-6

for example

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                   <h3 class="title">Taxes</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" class="btn btn-bold btn-sm btn-success">button</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And for removing space, as you are using "bootstrap cards" which define padding which create white space so remove that by adding p-0

For example

```
    <div class="card-header p-0">
  <div class="card-body p-0">
```